# Как в mysql обновить запись в конкретной строке

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli, crud

Есть такая запись в бд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно обновить те значения, на которые направил стрелки. Как это сделать?
Есть такой код:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET settingProxy=REPLACE(settingProxy, 'generatepress2', 'generatepress3') WHERE option_value
```

Comment: `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value=REPLACE(settingProxy, 'generatepress2', 'generatepress3') WHERE option_id IN(40, 41)`  попробуйте так, и у вас нету колоны `settingProxy`

Comment: если таблица носит название wp_options тогда UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='новое значение для строки с option_id 40' WHERE option_id=40; UPDATE wp_options SET option_value='новое значение для строки с option_id 41' WHERE option_id=41;